# Modify SOAP headers with Zeep

Tags: xml, python-3.x, soap, wsdl, zeep

I would like to make a Soap connection under python 3 with Zeep (https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html). But i don't understand how change the headers and body of xml !!

I want to have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www...." xmlns:ns2="http://schemas....">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:UsernameToken>
            <Username>__USERNAME__</Username>
            <Password>__PASSWORD__</Password>
            <Reference>__REFERENCE__</Reference>
        </ns2:UsernameToken>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:requestAd/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have done:

```python
"""Doc Placeholder."""

from zeep import Client
from zeep import Settings
from zeep.xsd import ComplexType
from zeep.xsd import Element
from zeep.xsd import String as xString

settings = Settings(strict=False,
                    xml_huge_tree=True,
                    extra_http_headers={'http://www....', 'http://schemas...'})
wsdl = 'https://.......?wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, settings=settings)

header = Element('UsernameToken', ComplexType([Element('Username', xString()),
                                              Element('Password', xString()),
                                              Element('Reference', xString()),
                                               ]))
header_value = header(UsernameToken={'Username': '__USERNAME__',
                                     'Password': '__PASSWORD__',
                                     'Reference': '__REFERENCE__'})
```

My error is :

```sh
TypeError: ComplexType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'UsernameToken'. 
Signature: `Username: xsd:string, Password: xsd:string, Reference: xsd:string`
```

Notes:
I tried all the solutions in the [documentation](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/headers.html) but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this same issue with zeep, I used the `get_type()` method to nest data in the soap call.

```python
"""index.py"""

import zeep

settings = zeep.Settings(strict=False,
                         xml_huge_tree=True,
                         extra_http_headers={'http://www....',
                                             'http://schemas...'})
wsdl = 'https://.......?wsdl'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl, settings=settings)
usernameTokenRef = client.get_type('ns2:UsernameToken')
usernameTokenValues = usernameTokenRef(Username='__USERNAME__',
                                       Password='__PASSWORD__',
                                       Reference='__REFERENCE__')

# pass args for UsernameToken into header of soap call
# using _soapheaders arg when calling a service
response = client.service.SomeService(_soapheaders={'UsernameToken':
                                      usernameTokenValues})
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Glad to have you apart of the community!
Please be sure to checkout our help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

In this case the error message is pretty informative, because there is only one child element of the Header element you do not need to specify it, Zeep will infer it.

The error message is saying that when trying to render the complex type it was expecting "Username", "Password" and "Reference", but got "UsernameToken" instead.

Your code works as written if you remove the keyword argument "UsernameToken", here's a working version, note that you need to pass the header in a list:

```
headerQ = Element('Header', ComplexType([
  Element('{http://test_ns.com}UsernameToken', ComplexType(
    Sequence([
      Element('Username', String()),
      Element('Password', String()),
      Element('Reference', String())
    ]))
  )
]))
header_value = headerQ({'Username': '__USERNAME__', 'Password': '__PASSWORD__', 
  'Reference': '__REFERENCE__'})
client.set_default_soapheaders([header_value])
```

This generated the following soap header:

```
<soap-env:Header>
  <Header>
    <ns0:UsernameToken xmlns:ns0="http://test_ns.com">
      <Username>__USERNAME__</Username>
      <Password>__PASSWORD__</Password>
      <Reference>__REFERENCE__</Reference>
    </ns0:UsernameToken>
  </Header>
</soap-env:Header>
```